# Convert binary string to decimal

Tags: r

I have a question on data conversion from binary to decimal. Suppose I have a binary pattern like this:

```
pattern<-do.call(expand.grid, replicate(5, 0:1, simplify=FALSE))
pattern
   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5
1     0    0    0    0    0
2     1    0    0    0    0
3     0    1    0    0    0
4     1    1    0    0    0
5     0    0    1    0    0
6     1    0    1    0    0
7     0    1    1    0    0
8     1    1    1    0    0
9     0    0    0    1    0
10    1    0    0    1    0
11    0    1    0    1    0
12    1    1    0    1    0
13    0    0    1    1    0
14    1    0    1    1    0
15    0    1    1    1    0
16    1    1    1    1    0
17    0    0    0    0    1
18    1    0    0    0    1
19    0    1    0    0    1
20    1    1    0    0    1
21    0    0    1    0    1
22    1    0    1    0    1
23    0    1    1    0    1
24    1    1    1    0    1
25    0    0    0    1    1
26    1    0    0    1    1
27    0    1    0    1    1
28    1    1    0    1    1
29    0    0    1    1    1
30    1    0    1    1    1
31    0    1    1    1    1
32    1    1    1    1    1
```

I'm wondering in R what is the easiest way to convert each row to a decimal value? and versus. such as:

```
00000->0
10000->16
...
01111->15
```

Comment: By the way, `do.call` is unnecessary in your data creation step....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
res <- strtoi(apply(pattern,1, paste, collapse=""), base=2)
res
#[1]  0 16  8 24  4 20 12 28  2 18 10 26  6 22 14 30  1 17  9 25  5 21 13 29  3
#[26] 19 11 27  7 23 15 31
```

You could try `intToBits` to convert back to the `binary`:

```
 pat2 <- t(sapply(res, function(x) as.integer(rev(intToBits(x)))))[,28:32]
 pat1 <- as.matrix(pattern)
 dimnames(pat1) <- NULL
identical(pat1, pat2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks, akrun! Do you know how to reverse the integers to the pattern format?

Comment: `strtoi()` is vectorized. No `apply()` necessary: `strtoi(do.call(paste0, as.data.frame(pattern)), base = 2)` (still slower than @nicola)

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
    as.matrix(pattern) %*% 2^((ncol(pattern)-1):0)
```

Comment: Thanks, nicola. May you know how to reverse the decimal to the binary pattern?

Comment: If `res` is what you obtain from my line, try `matrix((rep(res,each=5) %/% (2^(4:0)) %%2),ncol=5,byrow=TRUE)`. This supposing that your numbers are 5 binary digits.

Comment: I'd just note that, while @akrun solution is certainly valid, it can be hundreds of times slower than mine.

Comment: Nicola, it would be very useful if you added an explanation of how this solution works.